# Convert Json from SQL Table

Tags: json, sql-server-2016

I'm using `SQL Server 2016`. I want to return the `Json` in the given format.

Select statement

```
SELECT Country,[Arm Export],[Food Export] FROM Table
```

Expected `Json` Format

```
[
  {
    "India":{
             "Arm Export": 30,
             "Food Export": 50
            }
  },
  {
   "USA":{
          "Arm Export": 90,
          "Food Export": 5
         }
  },
  {
   "Russia":{
             "Arm Export": 90,
             "Food Export": 5
            }
  }
]
```

Any help will be appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT'['+stuff(
                (SELECT ',{"'+Country+'":{"Arm Export": '+convert(varchar,[Arm Export])+',"Food Export": '+convert(varchar,[Food Export])+'}}'
                   FROM TABLE
                   FOR XML Path('')),1,1,'')+']'[Detail]
```

output will be...

```
[
  {
    "India":{
             "Arm Export": 30,
             "Food Export": 50
            }
  },
  {
   "USA":{
          "Arm Export": 90,
          "Food Export": 5
         }
  },
  {
   "Russia":{
             "Arm Export": 90,
             "Food Export": 5
            }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Nithin, But is it not possible using FOR JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your output exactly as defined in the question, then Nithin's answer is probably the best.

If the output can be slightly different, you could try `FOR JSON PATH`, something like so:

```
SELECT Country, 
  [Arm Export] AS 'Export.Arm Export',
  [Food Export] AS 'Export.Food Export'
  FROM dbo.tb_CountryExport
  FOR JSON PATH;
```

That would give you an output like so:

```
[
  {
    "Country": "Russia",
    "Export": {
      "Arm Export": 90,
      "Food Export": 5
    }
  },
  {
    "Country": "India",
    "Export": {
      "Arm Export": 30,
      "Food Export": 50
    }
  },
  {
    "Country": "USA",
    "Export": {
      "Arm Export": 90,
      "Food Export": 5
    }
  }
]
```

But as I said, that output might not be what you want.

Niels